# Extruding only extrudes in 1 direction

Tags: mesh

I am trying to extrude the center of a barrel.

[image]

The model on the left side shows what it should look like.
The model on the right side shows how it goes wrong for me.
I would like to extrude to all sides so that it looks like the left image.
However, it only extrudes to one direction.

I have also tried "e" and Alt + s, but that also gives me a weird result:
[image]

How can I extrude to all sides?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Why use ALT + S, wouldn't using normal scaling be simpler (defaulting to the global coordinates instead of the normals)?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Weird effects of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> commend are probabliy caused by a non-uniform objectìs scale. By applying the scale before running it, all should work as expected.

[image]

If you don't want to apply the scale to your object you can scale the faces and set the Z value to 1 in order to keep the up/down faces flat.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but the other solution is simpler.